# Conjugating "to be" with a plural country name (e.g. British Virgin Islands)

Tags: verbs

I recently used the sentence 'The British Virgin Islands are a lovely place to sail.' in an article for a client.

When it was published, the editor changed ARE to IS. My feeling is this is incorrect and awkward, and does not read well. After trying to find out an answer to this - how to conjugate where the country name is plural, I could not find concrete examples. All searches with complete sentences that I found use ARE.

For lack of a better resources, I checked it with Pro Writing Aid and Grammarly. Pro Writing Aid stated that IS is correct and ARE is wrong, and Grammarly said exactly the opposite.

I ran the following iterations through Grammarly, which all showed as correct:

"Scotland **is** a lovely place to sail."

"The islands **are** a lovely place to sail."

"The Elizabeth Islands **are** a lovely place to sail."

"The Virgin Islands **are** a lovely place to sail."

"The British Virgin Islands **is** a lovely place to sail."

Can anyone direct me to some hard and fast guidance for how to deal with a country with a plural in the name, and which is correct in this instance for the British Virgin Islands?

There are only a handful of relevant countries, and most of them are used with a "The" too.

- Philippines
- Marshall Islands
- Bahamas
- Maldives
- Netherlands
- United States

Any others?

Given that I mostly write about sailing, and often about sailing in lovely tropical places like the BVIs and Bahamas, this has come up before and will come up again.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes these things just don't make sense. Certainly it feels wrong to say "The United States are the largest exporter of [whatever]". Despite the word "states", the sentence is about a single country, not dozens of states. I don't feel so strongly about "The British Virgin Islands" but that's probably because I don't normally mention that country in sentences.

Here's the thing: it probably doesn't matter what is right and what is wrong. Some people will think you're wrong whether you go with "is" or "are" in this case.

I would recommend avoiding the construct "Country X is a " when you are writing about a country with a name that sounds plural. You could easily go with "The sailing is lovely in the British Virgin Islands" or the like in order to avoid it.

Comment: That's a good point. Just avoid that construct in the future!